# What is wrong with this SPI implementation

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi, hardware, digital-communications

I designed a system with RaspberryPi and STM32F407's, communicating with each other via SPI interfaces.

For the last 3 months, tests were OK but yesterday a RaspberryPi and 2 of  STM32F407's SPI ports were burn out. I don't know why. Everything was working, I went to sleep, everything was burned out in the morning.

Here is the implementation sketch:

[image: Topology sketch]

[image: Modules' real pictures]

PCB's are 15 cm long. SPI lines are parallel. No chip-select lines are used. No termination resistance used. SPI frequency is 200 kHz. Power supplies are 5V 1A usb charger for RaspberryPi, LM2576 3.3V circuits (implemented by myself) converting 24V to 3.3V for MCU's.

I hot plugged my modules around 10 times with no problem (why hot plugging would be a problem with SPI?) although according to Wikipedia article, SPI is not hot pluggible.

1. So, what could possibly caused that damage? Standing waves? Hot plugging? Or maybe power supply? How can I find the root of this issue?
2. Do I need to use optic isolators (or cmos buffers?) for each of MCU unit?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "burned out"? Was there physical damage?

Comment: It seems so. RaspberryPi's mcu was too hot to touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a very long SPI bus running across several PCBs. Not only is this not recommended for SPI — it was originally designed for chip-to-chip communications on a single PCB — you have it connected directly to your CPUs without any electrical buffering.

Any induced transient (which could include ESD while hot-plugging) on any of the bus lines could easily drive any of your CPUs into "CMOS latchup", in which a parasitic SCR is activated that essentially shorts Vdd to ground. Physical damage from the resulting temperature rise can be permanent.

SPI is particularly easy to buffer, since each of the lines is unidirectional. You should include such buffers on the next revision of each of your PCBs.

Comment: Do you think any electrical buffer (like [4050](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4050B.pdf) or [74245](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/74/74AC245.pdf) ) is enough or optical isolation is mandatory?

Comment: No, I don't think you need optoisolation. Any electrical buffer that's rated for a reasonable level of ESD should be fine.

Comment: I have tried to buffer with 4050 and MAX485 so far, but they can not successfully transmit the clock signal. I'll try some other ic's tomorrow. 

If I understand correctly, I don't need to be afraid of ESD if I use a buffer with ESD protection? Then I may hot plug my modules, right?

Comment: You won't damage them electrically, but there are other issues with your hot-plug scheme. Since you don't use the chip selects, which normally provide the byte alignment of the data on the SPI bus, you could plug in a module in the middle of a transaction, and it would be forever out of sync with the rest of the system.

Comment: I used 74HC244 for buffering and for the first few tests it was OK. I hot plugged my module several times and there is nothing burned out. The sync problem is not observed mostly, when it occurred my software took care of it. But then, interestingly the buffers are burned out. I replaced them, hot plugged my module and then all buffers burned out again. I'm out of the buffer chips, so I'll have to wait till tomorrow for more tests.

Comment: When you hot-plug, are you making sure that ground connects first, then Vcc, then all the data lines?

Comment: No, it is absolutely random. I use DSUB-9 connectors, so I can not decide connection order. But I think I get the idea. You mean if I connect data lines before VCC and if a line is logic 1, then cmos latch-up may occur, right? If so, I may use TTL devices on the bus side and convert them to CMOS levels on the mcu sides. I think this could work.

Comment: I read a few articles and decided that hot plugging is another story. I need to continue without hot plugging feature, and then add it later. I think stopping SPI communication during module insertion is enough to prevent CMOS latch up.